# Generate link in JQuery using ASP.NET MVC Url.Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, caching, url-rewriting

I'm generating the list of links like this:

```
$('#latestNews').append('<li><a href="<%= Url.Action("Details", "Article") %>/' + key + '">' + val + '</a></li>');
```

And on the Index page link looks like:

```
<a href="/En/Article/Details/6">Title</a>
```

But, on the /En/Article/Details/6 page - generated link looks like:

```
<a href="/En/Article/Details/6/6">Title</a>
```

I've tried `$('#latestNews').append('<li><a href="<%= Url.Action("Details", "Article") %>?id=' + key + '">' + val + '</a></li>');` It works ok, but then caching does not work.

My controller code:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = Int32.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "id,language", SqlDependency = "database:Articles")] //Articles will be added rarely so i think it'll be nice to cache them
public ActionResult Details(string id, string language)
{..}
```

My route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", 
                "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { language = "En", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

So how to generate Url in a better way?

**UPDATED:**

```
 $.post('<%= Url.Action("GetLatest", "News") %>', function (data) {               
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    $('#latestNews').append('<li><%= Url.ActionLink(val, "Details", "Article", new { id = key }, null) %></li>');                    
                });
                $('#news').show();
            }, "json");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your key & val variables are in JavaScript so that isn't going to work with the Url Helper. You could change your script to look something like this:

**EDIT: fixed bug - changed {id = null} to { id = String.Empty }**

```
 $.post('<%= Url.Action("GetLatest", "News") %>', function (data) {               
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    $('#latestNews').append('<li><a href="<%= Url.Action("Details", "Article", new { id = String.Empty}) %>/' + key +'">' + val + '</a></li>');                    
                });
                $('#news').show();
            }, "json");
```

So, the MVC Url.Action() method is just giving you the first part of the url. Then jQuery will add `key` onto the end of the url and add `val` as the text for the anchor at runtime.

I think that's the easiest way of doing it without refactoring the code too much.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm doing it right now, it is the 2nd line of my question. The problem is when i am at the details page Url.Action gives /En/Article/Details/6 + /key = /En/Article/Details/6/6

Comment: I've edited the code above to pass in an {id = null} route value. Your issue is arising because Url.Action() will be using the current value of "id" on the details page.

Comment: assigning null gives CS0828: Cannot assign <null> to anonymous type property. So i changed it to ***new {id = String.Empty}***. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to generate the link is to pass the *id* directly to the *Action* method (and not to append it manually). Even better is to use the *ActionLink* instead of the *Action* method:

```
$('#latestNews').append('<li><%= Url.ActionLink(val, "Details", "Article", new { Id = key }, null) %></li>');
```

Comment: it shows Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'val' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Replace `val` with the text of the link

Comment: I'm getting key, val values from server, look please on my $.post request. I have to add these values dynamically. I've tried $('#latestNews').append('<li><%= Url.ActionLink(' + val + ', "Details", "Article", new { id = ' + key + ' }, null) %></li>');  and it shows **Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal**